# Change detection solution for self-nested component

Tags: angular

I have a component with this structure

```
<comp>
    <comp> </comp>
    <comp> </comp>
</comp>
```

A change / click event in a deeply nested child will cause a update possibly to the whole "tree". For example: the tick on left side of this image below

https://www.jstree.com/

[image]

Which change detection strategy I should apply to this kind of problem?
I already tried using **EventEmitter** that emit a "Selected node" event from deep child, up till the top-most node

I also think that all nodes can subscribe to a single **Subject** and do the update

What is the correct solution to apply to this kind of problem?

Comment: OnPush seems suitable here for performance reasons. As long as the `Input` references haven't changed or an `Output` event hasn't fired, it will skip the entire subtree on checking.  Just make sure to use immutables for `Input` binding to a single node.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the way was that your component has as `@Input` children, parent and level, so you can recursive change the values, you can see an example in [this response in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56376237/create-tree-view-with-horizontal-and-vertical-lines-showing-the-connectivity-usi/56381812#56381812). The "key" is declare a variable "self" and the inputs

```
self=this;
@Input() level: number;
@Input() children: any;
@Input() parent: any;
```

And make some like

```
<li *ngFor="let item of children">
    {{item.label}}
    <ul recursive *ngIf="item.children" 
        [children]="item.children" 
        [parent]="self" 
        [level]="level!=undefined?level+1:0">
            </ul>
</li>
```