# Angular Material Flat Tree Parent Children Graphical Representaion

Tags: angular, filetree, angular-tree-component

I want to show Parent Children graphical representation on Angular Material Flat Tree.

**This is the design :**

[image]

> Here is the [**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-flat-tree-graphical-reperesentaion?embed=1&file=app/tree-flat-overview-example.html) what i done so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200240/discussion-between-jsmith-and-anzil-khan).

Comment: like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56376237/create-tree-view-with-horizontal-and-vertical-lines-showing-the-connectivity-usi/56381812#56381812? or you want dragable

Comment: @Eliseo , your above solution is nested DOM structure. But mine DOM structure is flat. You can't style flat DOM structure like nested DOM structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**FIRST SOLUTION**

here is the [stackBlitz Demo](https://mat-tree-with-dragging-2-e2rgyu.stackblitz.io)

here is the [stackBlitz editable link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-tree-with-dragging-2-e2rgyu?file=app/tree-flat-overview-example.html)

I've made a recursive call on every visible node reffering to the node index using `treeControl.dataNodes.indexOf(node)`

here is the recursive function:

```
  recNode( arr:any[], data:any[], index:number, maxIndex:number ):any[] {

    if ( arr === undefined )
      arr = [];

    for ( let i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {

          index++

          if ( index === maxIndex ) return ( [ true, index, arr ] );
          if ( data[i].children.length ) {

            let res = this.recNode( arr, data[i].children, index, maxIndex )
            index = res[1];

            if ( res[0] === true ) {

              arr.splice( 0, 0, ( i !== ( data.length - 1 ) ) )         
              return ( [ true, index, arr ] );

            }

        }

    }

    return ( [ false, index, arr ] );

  }
```

this returns an array of `true` `false` values for your `[ngClass]`

then in html I call that function as so

```
<li *ngFor="let r of recNode( undefined, dataSource.data, -1, treeControl.dataNodes.indexOf( node ) )[2]; [ngClass]="{'node-arrow': r, 'node-arrow-empty': !r}" ></li>
```

and finally I've created another class in the css called `node-arrow-empty` without borders

```
   .node-arrow-nox {
      position: relative;
      // min-width: 48px;
      // min-height: 48px;
      .node-arrow {
        position: relative;
        min-width: 48px;
        min-height: 48px;
        &:before {
          content: "";
          position: absolute;
          top: -20px;
          left: 20px;
          border-left: 1px solid $copounsCount;
          bottom: 0;
        }
      }
      .node-arrow-empty {
        position: relative;
        min-width: 48px;
        min-height: 48px;
        &:before {
          content: "";
          position: absolute;
          top: -20px;
          left: 20px;
          bottom: 0;
        }
      }
    }
```

depending on weither the value in the array is `true` or `false` it switches in the html between the two classes.

**SECOND SOLUTION**

[stackBlitz DEMO](https://mat-tree-with-dragging-2-wccygg.stackblitz.io)

[stackBlitz editable link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-tree-with-dragging-2-wccygg?file=app%2Ftree-flat-overview-example.html)

the other solution would be to keep track of last element in array by adding for example a `isLast:boolean` property. Of course if the datas you are dealing with are dynamic you need to find a way to dinamically change that value.

Once the `isLast` is filled you make a recursive call which will find the previous sibling with `current node level - 1`. That being said you will check 2 things. First thing is, is the node classes contains `n-last` (which is the class name I gave to Html representing last element of parent array) and second thing retrieve the class `n-{{node-level}}`.

By recursively (you can make a non recursive method if you wan't to) retrieving the `previousElementSibling` which has class `n-3` or `n-2` ... to `n-0` you can check if each of this element contains a `n-last` class. You push the `true` or `false` into an array and just as the first solution switch between class `node-arrow` and `node-arrow-empty`.

here is the recursive function

```
  dummy( el:any, arr:any[], level:number ) {

    let classes = el.className;

    if ( arr === undefined )
     arr = [];
    else {

     arr.splice( 0, 0, classes.includes( 'n-last' ) );

    }

    let np = /(?!n-)\d+/g;

    let m = classes.match( np );
    let nLevel = parseInt( m[0] );
    nLevel--;

    if ( nLevel < 0 ) return ( arr );

    while ( parseInt( el.className.match( np )[0] ) !== nLevel ) {

      el = el.previousElementSibling;

    }

    arr = this.dummy(el, arr, nLevel);

    return (arr);

  }
```

the HTML (here is only parent node but same thing for child)

```
<mat-tree-node #refP   class="parent-node {{'n-' + node.level}} " *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: grpNode;" matTreeNodePadding matTreeNodePaddingIndent="0" cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="node" [ngClass]="{'no-child': !node.children.length, 'n-last': node.isLast}">
  <span class="node-arrow-nox d-flex">
    <li [ngClass]="{'node-arrow': !r , 'node-arrow-empty': r}" *ngFor="let r of dummy(refP, undefined, node.level)"></li>
  </span>
  <button class="node-toggle" mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.filename" [disabled]="!node.children.length">
    <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror toggle-arrow">
      {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'play_arrow' : 'play_arrow'}}
    </mat-icon>
  </button>
  <div class="node-icon icon-h-arw"></div>
  <div class="node-name">{{node.isLast}}-{{node.accntCode}} <span>: :</span> {{node.name}} </div>
</mat-tree-node>
```

as you can see I'm passing element to the dummy fucntion with a template variable called `#refP`

and here are the `PARENTNODE` and `CHILDNODE` declaration:

```
export class PARENTNODE {
  id: string;
  isLast: boolean;
  ...
  actAsSupplier: boolean;
}

/* Flat node with expandable and level information */
export class CHILDNODE {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public isLast: boolean,
    ...
    public actAsSupplier: boolean,
  ){}
}
```

**THIRD SOLUTION**

I won't code it but I'll try to explain it.

This is kind of similar to the previous solution except your could parse when tree is changed (swapping, deletion, add) the data and add a property like `divType` populated with `true` or `false` and call it in your html as so

```
 <li *ngFor="let r of node.divType" [ngClass]="{'node-arrow': r, 'node-arrow-empty': !r}" ></li>
```