# Connecting child with lines to parent in mat tree

Tags: css, angular, tree, angular-material

I need to build a mat tree as per the diagram given below.
[image]

I am done with the icons and boxes but I am not able to draw the lines. Can anyone help me with the lines?
I am using mat nested tree.
Here is the stackblitz link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qhper2
Mat icons is not loading in stackblitz. I only need the lines though.

Its possible through CSS by editing style for li and ul tag. But I am not that good at CSS. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: some time ago, I answer similar question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56376237/create-tree-view-with-horizontal-and-vertical-lines-showing-the-connectivity-usi/56381812#56381812. But it's not mat-tree, only an object with children an a recursive component

Comment: Is it possible to make the lines in the example given by me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it:

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="recursive">Recursive</mat-checkbox>
 <mat-card>
  <mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
   <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node">
    <li>
      <div class="mat-tree-node">  {{node.item}}</div>
    </li>
   </mat-nested-tree-node>
  <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChildren">
    <li class="example-tree-container">
      <div class="mat-tree-node">
        <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
                [matTreeNodeToggleRecursive]="recursive"
              [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.filename">
          <mat-icon>
            {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
          </mat-icon>
        </button>
        {{node.item}}
    </div>
    <ul class="example-tree-nested-node">
      <div  *ngIf="treeControl.isExpanded(node)">
      <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
   </mat-nested-tree-node>
 </mat-tree>
```

You can see full code here:

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-tree-nested?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)