# Angular: List view from multidimensional array

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array

I have following data structure:

```
{
    'TeamLead': 'Andrew',
    'subordinate': [{
            'Name': 'Daniel',
            'subordinate': [{
                    'Name': 'Steve',
                    'subordinate': [{
                            'Name': 'Steve',
                            'subordinate': [{
                                    'Name': 'Joe',
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have to show all subordinates list under team lead in Angular, similar to this and dimension of array is not fixed one :

[image]

Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56376237/create-tree-view-with-horizontal-and-vertical-lines-showing-the-connectivity-usi/56381812#56381812

Comment: @salahuddin You can always upvote if you like an answer :)

Comment: @GouravGarg Done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Angular material Tree](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples) structure to display these.

This is very simple library to use.