# angular infinite loop use ngFor

Tags: angular

what's the better solution for ngFor loop to n times, see HTML below (has sub folder loop 3 times now hardcoded). how to do an infinite loop  x times.
Basically, I have a flat array, but I don't know the subfolder levels.
loop thru folder  parentId vs typeId

```
flatArray=[
         {
            "type_name":"(Unspecified)",
            "node_type":"E",
            "type_id":1,
            "parent_id":"80"
         },
         {
            "type_name":"CNF-CUBLD-BLDR",
            "node_type":"E",
            "type_id":86,
            "parent_id":3
         },
         {
            "type_name":"CNF-CUSPG-COSPG",
            "node_type":"E",
            "type_id":80,
            "parent_id":130
         },
         {
            "type_name":"CNF-CUSPG-EXSTU",
            "node_type":"E",
            "type_id":142,
            "parent_id":45
         },
         {
            "type_name":"Colloquium",
            "node_type":"E",
            "type_id":105,
            "parent_id":48
         {
            "type_name":"CON-CUBLD-BLDR",
            "node_type":"E",
            "type_id":111,
            "parent_id":3
         },
         {
            "type_name":"CON-CUBLD-CEPS",
            "node_type":"E",
            "type_id":130,
            "parent_id":45
         },
         {
            "type_name":"CON-CUSPG-COSPG",
            "node_type":"E",
            "type_id":77,
            "parent_id":3
         },
         {
            "type_name":"CON-CUSPG-EXSTU",
            "node_type":"E",
            "type_id":143,
            "parent_id":45
         },
         {
            "type_name":"Concert",
            "node_type":"E",
            "type_id":191,
            "parent_id":188,
         },
         {
            "type_name":"Conference",
            "node_type":"E",
            "type_id":50,
            "parent_id":48,
         },
         {
            "type_name":"Continuing Ed",
            "node_type":"C",
            "type_id":44,
            "parent_id":3,
         },
         {
            "type_name":"COP-CUBLD-BLDR",
            "node_type":"E",
            "type_id":87,
            "parent_id":3
         },
         {
            "type_name":"COP-CUBLD-CEPS",
            "node_type":"E",
            "type_id":132,
            "parent_id":45
         }
         ]



    <ul *ngFor="let a of this.allTypes; let i=index">
                <li *ngIf="a.parent_id === c.type_id">
                    <span *ngIf="a.node_type==='F'" >
                        <a class="tooltipButton" (click)="this.showNextlevel(a.type_id, i);">Folder: {{a.type_name}}</a>
                          <ul *ngFor="let b of this.allTypes">
                              <li *ngIf="b.parent_id === a.type_id">
                                  <div  *ngIf="b.node_type==='F'" (click)="this.getParentId(b.type_id)">
                                      Folder: {{b.type_name}}
                                      <ul *ngFor="let c of this.allTypes">
                                          <li *ngIf="c.parent_id === b.type_id">
                                              <div  *ngIf="c.node_type==='F'" (click)="this.getParentId(c.type_id)">
                                                  Folder: {{c.type_name}}
                                              </div>                                  
                                              <span><a *ngIf="c.node_type==='E'" (click)="this.goToEventTypeDetail(c.type_id)" class="tooltipButton">Event: {{c.type_name}}</a> </span>                                
                                          </li>
                                      </ul>
                                  </div>                                  
                                  <span><a *ngIf="b.node_type==='E'" (click)="this.goToEventTypeDetail(b.type_id)" class="tooltipButton">Event: {{b.type_name}}</a> </span>                                
                              </li>
                          </ul>
                    </span>
                    <span><a *ngIf="a.node_type==='E'" (click)="this.goToEventTypeDetail(a.type_id)" class="tooltipButton">Event: {{a.type_name}}</a></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: do you want to create a recursive component? take a look to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55305905/how-can-i-create-a-nested-recursive-table-that-can-drill-down-x-levels-in-angul/55315414#55315414), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61905207/angular-8-implementing-a-hierarchical-list-recursively-with-dynamic-expansion/61911633#61911633) or [this another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68233888/angular-how-to-create-a-dynamic-menu-in-angular-from-database-data-asp-net-co/68235557#68235557) or ...

Comment: thanks Eliseo. SO example works well for me. Now I want to have options to Expand All vs Collapse All. Is this possible?

Comment: never mind. resolved my issue by set  all items expanded to true.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it may helpful for you.

In your component ts

```
@Input() items: any[];

public isArray(item: any) {
    return item instanceof Array;
}
```

In your component html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    ...
    <ng-container *ngIf="isArray(item.key)">
        <your-component [items]="item.key"></your-component>
    </ng-container>
    ...
</div>
```