# How to create hierarchal tree in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular12

I have the requirement that is list and when clicking each list it should load API and need to bind another list inside the which one is clicked. So this should happen for all list. What is the best way to do this hierarchal tree list in angular.

Example :

- list1

  - child1

    - childchild1

      - childchildchild1

        - childchildchildchild1
      - childchildchild2
    - childchild2
  - child2
  - child3
- list2
- list3
- list4

So the same of list1 should happen for all list like list2, list3 and list4. The child list should load only when we clicking the parent list. Appreciate with stackBlitz example. Thank you

Comment: Just build a component that of a single treenode that has an ngfor in it that also adds the childs as treenodes inside of it. After that just pass your hierarchal tree parent to the component and everything is rendered recursively and you have your tree

Comment: We're using a component from ngPrime: tree (and treetable) for that. They have loads of examples as well. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/tree

Comment: e.g. (much more complex) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56376237/create-tree-view-with-horizontal-and-vertical-lines-showing-the-connectivity-usi/56381812#56381812